# Chef Issue bootstrapping windows VM using winrm via https

Tags: windows, https, chef, winrm

Chef Server(RHEL 6.5): 11.16.4
Windows endpoint: Windows 2008

The bootstrapping works fine over http (with `winrm config allowUnEncrypeted = true` and `basic auth = true`).

Now we are trying same thing over https(but with `basic auth = false` and `AllowUnEncrypted = false`)

The self signed certificate is generated(with private key) and I've verified telnet over port 443.

To check connectivity, I've run the following command from my terminal (windows 7),

```
winrs -r:https://<fqdn Of windows EP>:443 -u:administrator -p:password_1 ipconfig
```

which works fine after adding the self signed certificate under trusted root certification authorities.

Error while bootstrapping from chef server:

```
[root@v-ng25-rhel6u5-tpm722 ~]# knife bootstrap windows winrm v-ngibm71tpm7222k8.example.co.in -x Administrator -P 'password_1' -p 443

Waiting for remote response before bootstrap.at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate
..at depth 0 - 18: self signed certificate


ERROR: No response received from remote node after 1.84 minutes, giving up.
ERROR: OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

Ideally if the winrs command works, so should this.

Any help/pointers is much appreciated.

Comment: I implemented the changes mentioned at link
https://github.com/gswallow/knife-windows/commit/d04c835cfff1260017b91a799168e90b931cad6a

by adding the option --no-ssl-peer-verification option but it did not help